# Making a class and function interchangeable in Typescript types.d.ts library definition

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to type a library that exposes its interface via an interchangeable value.

```
import Client from "client";

// The following two lines both achieve the same result.
new Client();
Client();
```

This client may be constructed via the new keyword or implicitly without as a function call. How can I express this in a types.d.ts file? My initial attempt resulting in the following invalid code.

```
declare class ClientObj {}
declare function ClientFunc();
type Client = ClientObj | ClientFunc;
export default Client;
```

I don't believe `type` works how I expect here however.

Comment: FWIW, I would type it one way or the other and pretend the other way didn't exist in your code. (<subjective>"Optional `new`" is and always was a silly idea.</subjective>) If `x = Client(); console.log(x instanceof Client);` shows `true`, type it as a constructor; if `false`, type it as a function and assign the appropriate return type to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional way something like this is done in TypeScript's own standard library (see [the typings for `Date`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ec77bff33226fb01f4e38b20e481f8c1fcd9e6c0/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L729-L907) for example) is to declare two `interface`s; one for the instance type (with the intended `class` name) and another for the constructor type (usually the same name with `Constructor` appended to it).  And then you declare the class constructor value as a `var` or `const`.  If you want to give the constructor added functionality, such as being callable without `new`, you can do it inside the `XXXConstructor` interface.  Like so:

```
interface Client {
  foo(): void;
}

interface ClientConstructor {
  new(): Client;
  (): Client;
}

declare const Client: ClientConstructor;
```

Here `Client` represents an instance with a `foo()` method.  And `ClientConstructor` has both a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) and a [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures).

---

Let's test it:

```
const constructed = new Client();
constructed.foo();

const called = Client();
called.foo();
```

Looks good.  Both ways of creating a `Client` compile without warning.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIBtgXMg3gKGWRgHsSAKASgC5kA3E4AEwG58BfffUSWRFDFnCoSIAM5goAVwRgSUPIWQgIAdyq1B2MGyIa0mbW074mEBOjhQUCURINCwmw8LuSZcqG3y3xYZL4S0rIQTMgAvMpqDtpUbIHuIUwAdKQUlN4JAXDo6KERMeBxPjl5KWnFXEA)